# Django - form fields feeded from another field

Tags: python, django, forms

what is normal way to do such thing:
suppose that i have form for two choice fields - manufacturer and model. I would like user to choose manufacturer, than to choose specific model, which will be updated after first field is set. Is there way to do this using django (without reloading of the page) or should go with java ? (but then i would have to pass all of the models and let java do the filtering)

Comment: Uh, I'm pretty sure you mean `javascript` and not `java`.

Comment: Have you tried javascript update the form field method ?

Comment: yep, javascript. I didn't made that form yet - rigth now i'm looking for options - i know that javascript can do this for me, but i'd like to not to ues it ;)